# Property 'exampleProperty' does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to convert JS to TS for exsiting Vue components. I made an interface that determines the types of the props of the component like so:

```
interface DataTypes {
  questions: Array<string>;
  results: Array<string>;
  activeIndex: number;
}
```

Then, the properties in the component are declared like this:

```
data(): DataTypes {
    return {
      questions: [],
      results: [],
      activeIndex: 0
    };
  },
```

With the properties there are no issues, but when I use a prop in a computed prop, I'm getting a notification from VS code that "Property 'activeIndex' does not exist on type".

```
computed: {
    // Starts at 1
    activeNumber(): number {
      return this.activeIndex + 1;
    }
}
```

The script is encapsulated in an object and exported with `export default`.

I'm new to both Vue and TS and can't figure out what's the issue here.

Comment: How is it exporting within ./ExampleScript.ts ? Usually you don't separate and import your script into your vue component like this as it requires more effort to understand the component and decouples things that belong together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide your entire script block so I can debug further?

It's possible that you're not exporting `Vue.extend` but just a normal object.

If you don't use this, typescript will be unable to find your property.

Your script tag should export like this:

```
export default Vue.extend({
    ...
});
```

Unfortunately typescript support in Vue2 is quite poor as Vue wasn't originally built with typescript in mind. Vue3 is infinitely better as it's a full re-write using typescript so you have that to look forward to when it gains more adoption.

To leverage better typescript integration in Vue2 you can use the [Vue-Class-Component library](https://class-component.vuejs.org/). I'd recommend this, otherwise you will be fighting typescript a fair bit more.

Comment: Hi Jordan, thanks for your reply. It's true that I didn't export with Vue.extend as this is way it's done throughout the whole project. I updated my question to show how the component is imported.

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of how you are exporting your component? If you aren't using the class component syntax, you need to extend Vue in your import to use typescript. Preferably a minimal version of your component I can paste into my IDE and run so I can check for you? :)

Comment: Seen your new update @DSteman. You need to import Vue into your ts file and then change it to `export default Vue.extend({ ... });`. Without exporting this, your typescript won't work

Comment: Okay that's clear. I imported Vue and exported Vue.extend. A new error is being raised for the activeIndex computed prop though: "Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '(() => any) | ComputedOptions<any>' and 'number'." Any ideas?

Comment: Not too sure. I'd have to investigate a little further. Perhaps worth opening a new question for it. If you want to work with typescript in Vue2, I'd really suggest using the class syntax. What you're using right now is called the "options API". It really sucks for typescript. Take a look at the link in the bottom of my answer :)

Comment: I'll do that, thanks for the advice, this already helped a lot :)

Comment: No worries, thank you for working with me and providing me with the extra information so I could properly help! Feel free to upvote my answer if you think it deserves it ;)